# Webflux JWT Authorization not working fine

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux

I am following a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ard333/authentication-and-authorization-using-jwt-on-spring-webflux-29b81f813e78) about JWT in a spring reactive context (webflux).

The token generation is working fine, however the authorization is not working when I use the `Authorization` with `bearer`

Here is what I have done:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig{

    @Autowired private JWTReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired private SecurityContextRepository securityContext;

    @Bean public SecurityWebFilterChain configure(ServerHttpSecurity http){

        return http.exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint((swe , e) -> {
            return Mono.fromRunnable(()->{
                System.out.println( "authenticationEntryPoint user trying to access unauthorized api end points : "+
                                    swe.getRequest().getRemoteAddress()+
                                    " in "+swe.getRequest().getPath());
                swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            });
        }).accessDeniedHandler((swe, e) -> {
            return Mono.fromRunnable(()->{
                System.out.println( "accessDeniedHandler user trying to access unauthorized api end points : "+
                                    swe.getPrincipal().block().getName()+
                                    " in "+swe.getRequest().getPath());
                swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);                    
            });
        })
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .securityContextRepository(securityContext)
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll()
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and()
        .build();


    }
```

As you can see, I want to simply deny all not authorized requests other than login or options based ones.

The login is working fine and I'm getting a token.

[image]

But trying to logout (a tweak that I implemented my self to make it state-full since I m only learning) is not working.

Here is my logout controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(AuthController.AUTH)
public class AuthController {

    static final String AUTH = "/auth";

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authService;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> login(@RequestBody AuthRequestParam arp) {

        String username = arp.getUsername();
        String password = arp.getPassword();

        return authService.authenticate(username, password);
    }

    @PostMapping("/logout")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> logout(@RequestBody LogoutRequestParam lrp) {

        String token = lrp.getToken();

        return authService.logout(token);
    }

}
```

The logout request is as below:

[image]
[image]

As stated in images above, I believe that I m doing fine, however I m getting the error log message:

> authenticationEntryPoint user trying to access unauthorized api end points : /127.0.0.1:45776 in /auth/logout

Here is my security context content:

```
/**
 * we use this class to handle the bearer token extraction
 * and pass it to the JWTReactiveAuthentication manager so in the end 
 * we produce
 * 
 * simply said we extract the authorization we authenticate and 
 * depending on our implementation we produce a security context
 */

@Component
public class SecurityContextRepository implements ServerSecurityContextRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JWTReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange swe) {

        ServerHttpRequest request = swe.getRequest();

        String authorizationHeaderContent = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if( authorizationHeaderContent !=null &&  !authorizationHeaderContent.isEmpty() &&  authorizationHeaderContent.startsWith("Bearer ")){

                String token = authorizationHeaderContent.substring(7);

                Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token, token);
                return this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication).map((auth) -> {
                    return new SecurityContextImpl(auth);
                });

        }

        return Mono.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> save(ServerWebExchange arg0, SecurityContext arg1) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

I'm unable to see or find any issue or error that I have made. Where is the mistake?

Comment: a token is not a session. You cannot "logout" a token. Tokens have to expire.

Comment: I know that a token is not a session and it is a statless context related, but the needs justify the solution, we add to jwt a store to make it statefull, however thanks for the concern

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb can you add more code please ? or add a github project

Comment: @ElmaCherb https://github.com/MHTaleb/webflux_jjwt

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference in writing

```java
//Wrong
Jwts.builder()
   .setSubject(username)
   .setClaims(claims)
```

and

```java
//Correct
Jwts.builder()
   .setClaims(claims)
   .setSubject(username)
```

Indeed, look at `setSubject` method in the `DefaultJwtBuilder` class :

```java
@Override
public JwtBuilder setSubject(String sub) {
    if (Strings.hasText(sub)) {
        ensureClaims().setSubject(sub);
    } else {
        if (this.claims != null) {
            claims.setSubject(sub);
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

When `setSubject(username)` is called first, `ensureClaims()` creates a `DefaultClaims` without yours and if you call `setClaims(claims)` the precedent subject is lost ! This JWT builder is bogus.

Otherwise, you're importing the wrong Role class in `JWTReactiveAuthenticationManager`, you have to replace :

```
import org.springframework.context.support.BeanDefinitionDsl.Role;
```

by

```
import com.bridjitlearning.www.jwt.tutorial.domain.Role;
```

Last and not least, `validateToken()` will return always `false` because of the `check(token)`. `put` call is coming too late, you have to be aware of that. Either you remove this check or you move the `put` execution before calling the check method.

I'am not sure about what you want to do with `resignTokenMemory`, so i'll let you fix it by your own:

```java
public Boolean validateToken(String token) {
    return !isTokenExpired(token) && resignTokenMemory.check(token);
}
```

Another thing, your token is valid only 28,8 second, for testing raison i recommend you to `expiraiton * 1000`.

Comment: now that you mentioned all this, in the tutorial it was using the correct way, this is the second time I m facing this issue when order of call in a builder is important.
thanks :)

Comment: When order matters, the designer must force its clients to know about that order. When it’s hidden bugs are located hardly

Comment: [Sequential coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling) is the name of this anti-pattern